# Slider pro - how can I set delay

Tags: jquery, slider, delay

I am using [Slider Prod](http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/) (with autoplay) and I can't find where delay can be set.

Can I ask you for help?

Comment: What do you mean by delay?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

**autoplayDelay:5000;**

Sets the delay/interval (in milliseconds) at which the autoplay will run.

Default value: 5000

***DEMO***

```
$( '#slider' ).sliderPro({
    width: 960,
    height: 500,
    arrows: true,
    buttons: false,
    waitForLayers: true,
    fade: true,
    autoplay: false,
    autoScaleLayers: false,
    autoplayDelay:3000
});
```

Hope this can help you?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, thanks. I am stupid, I thought that this is delay for autoplay, not for delay between photos.

Answer (score 0):

You have the documentaion here: https://github.com/bqworks/slider-pro/blob/master/docs/api.md#1-properties

And a property:

**autoplayDelay**

Sets the delay/interval (in milliseconds) at which the autoplay will run.

Default value: 5000